# (Meteor) 'click' event doesnt get new value

Tags: meteor

I get stuck in this case:
I create a list of records in html:

```
{{#each data}}
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o btn-edit-ota" data-hotel-id="1"></i>
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o btn-edit-ota" data-hotel-id="2"></i>
...
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o btn-edit-ota" data-hotel-id="10"></i>
{{/each}}
```

I want to everytime I click on each item, it writes "hotel-id" of that item in console log; So, in js I create:

```
'click .btn-edit-ota': function (event, template) {
        var hid = $(event.target).data('hotel-id');
        console.log(hid);
}
```

And it works fine, it shows '1' in the console log when I click the 1st and so on '2' with 2nd, ...

In js, I have an autorun:

```
Template.myTemp.onRendered(function () {
    var self = this;
    self.autorun(function (computation) {
         ... //generate my list here...
    }
});
```

so whenever I change any checkboxs or filters or current page..., the autorun will run and I get a new list.

The problem here is when that autorun runs, and I get a new list.
e.g: now is:

```
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o btn-edit-ota" data-hotel-id="11"></i>
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o btn-edit-ota" data-hotel-id="12"></i>
...
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil-square-o btn-edit-ota" data-hotel-id="20"></i>
```

I click in the 1st, It shows '1' in console log. :((

It should show '11'. Because the HTML now is: **...data-hotel-id="11">**, not **...data-hotel-id="1">** any more.

It must be use the old data/html I think.
Something weirds happened with that 'click' event

```
$(event.target).data('hotel-id');
```

It doesnt get a new ID.

Anyone can tell me why this happened?
Many thanks.

Comment: I noticed that if I change to use $(event.target).attr('data-hotel-id') instead of $(event.target).data('hotel-id') It works fine. However I still dont understand why :I

Comment: 2 questions - 1) How are you generating your list in your `autorun`?; 2) What does the `data` helper look like that you're using in your `each`?

Comment: I get the list through Meteor.call().. and set it into a ReactiveVar. In the data helper, I just return that array so I can print it via {{#each}}

Comment: I found the solution that I can use HTML5 dataset API to get tag's attribute or jquery $..attr('data-hotel-id'). These always get data from Current target.